# Audrino mkr1500 keeps going offline

Tags: iot

I am using a MKR1500 with an Arduino SIM. I am able to upload the code on the device using the web editor. But when once I am done uploading the code, the device shows status offline and I am unable to check if the data is changing in the dashboard. I am running the below code to test. Also if i check when was the last time it was active, it generally shows before flashing. Also found that when I detach the device from the web UI and select it again, it shows up the last active timing as when it was detached. But during that time I saw it was inactive. Is there something that i am missing?
Can someone please help me with it.
Thanks!

```
int readSensor;
void setup() {
  // Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // This delay gives the chance to wait for a Serial Monitor without blocking if none is found
  delay(1500); 
  Serial.println("Hello world");
  // Defined in thingProperties.h
  initProperties();
  // Connect to Arduino IoT Cloud
  ArduinoCloud.begin(ArduinoIoTPreferredConnection);
  setDebugMessageLevel(2);
  ArduinoCloud.printDebugInfo();
}
void loop() {
  ArduinoCloud.update();
  // Your code here 
  int sensor1 = analogRead(A1);
  int carbonMonoxide = analogRead(A2);
  int methaneSensor = analogRead(A3);
  Serial.println(sensor1);
  Serial.println(carbonMonoxide);
  Serial.println(methaneSensor);
  delay(1000);
 }
void onADCvalueChange() {
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The mkr1500 is not compatible with the sim right only the mkr1400 is working with the sim SORRY!
Check The Page [store.arduino.cc/digital/sim](https://store.arduino.cc/digital/sim)

Comment: So can I use any other sim to make it work. Seems to be that my other SIM(T mobile, AT & T) also doesnt seem to work. The arduino sim seems to have some activation issue it seems, just heard back from the arduino team

Comment: I was able to get the MKR1500 online using a Soracom sim card. Seems to be that the T-mobile nbiot sim are a pian to get them talking to the cloud.. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I think 1500 is not built for GSM capibilitys please check what the mkr board is for